# CSS flyout div extending beyond overflow auto div

Tags: css

I have a sidebar whose contents I would like to scroll within the boundaries of the sidebar.  I would also like to have a "flyout" div that extends outside the boundaries of the sidebar.  Is such a thing possible?

Here is a jsFiddle to demonstrate my approach: http://jsfiddle.net/Takanudo/NE53A/3/

I have two sidebars.  Sidebar 1 has overflow set to auto.  In Sidebar 1 the flyout does not extend beyond the boundaries of Sidebar 1.  Sidebar 2 has overflow set to visible.  In Sidebar 2 the flyout works as desired.  Unfortunately, Sidebar 2 no longer scrolls.  Can I have both a scrolling sidebar with a flyout that extends beyond the boundary?  Is my approach incorrect?

Here is the CSS I'm using:

```
#main{
  float: left;
}
#sidebar2{
  background: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  float: right;
  overflow: visible;
}
#sidebar1{
  background: orange;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  float: right;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
.content{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.options{
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.flyout{
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 0;
  left: -300px;
  text-align: left;
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Don't know how CSS can fix this. Is JS an option? If yes, check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/NE53A/6/). Adding `position:absolute` and giving `left` and `top` attributes of the clicked area to the flyout.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working fiddle with a JS workaround.
http://jsfiddle.net/7TFn4/

`.flyout` is set to `position:absolute`.

```
$(".options").click(function(){
    $(".flyout", this).toggle();
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    $(this).children('.flyout').css('left',offset.left-300);
    $(this).children('.flyout').css('top',offset.top);
});
```